# Back To The Future: Why should Marty fade at all?

Tags: back-to-the-future

Other threads have posed the existence of "meta-time" at right-angles to ordinary time, allowing for a single universe in which time can be changed, but resolving the paradoxes. On that basis, however, why should Marty have begun to fade at all, since he comes from an "earlier" point in meta-time? Surely he should continue to exist, as although in the future where George and Lorraine never get together and the McFly kids are never born, Marty comes from an earlier meta-time, in the 1967 or 1968 of which he was born?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/89987/17024

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question - that addresses the question of whether the BTTF universe contains multiple parallel co-existing timelines, which, as the article points out, is not the case - there is a single timeline which can be altered. But it's also been suggested that there is a second temporal dimension, a "meta-time", which cannot be observed by us 4-dimensional beings but in which all the previous, erased timelines are stacked, as well as different potential futures (such as in Pt.3 where "Emmett Brown" and "Clint Eastwood" are superimposed on the gravestone in the photo).

Comment: I suppose I should have had text to go with my link. It was not intended as an answer or duplicate. It is just a related link that is actually related.

Comment: I especially liked the link back to Bob Gale and Robert Zemeckis QA.